# Spring security users only access to their group items

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

In my design, each user belongs to a specific group, so when a user creates an item only users from the **same user group** can view or edit the item, does spring security has anything to implement this scenario or I should implement it myself. I use spring oauth2 with JWT token?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security supports ACLs for Domain Objects, sounds like this might be what your after: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html